# How to workaround dependency conflicts in a Rust Cargo workspace for a CLI tool?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, cargo-features

I'm developing a CLI tool with several subcommands for different use cases. Here's my project structure:

```
project/
├── Cargo.toml 
└── crates/
    ├── project-foo/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── lib.rs (subcommand for 'foo')
    ├── project-bar/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── lib.rs (subcommand for 'bar')
    └── project-core/
        └── src/
            └── main.rs (main entry point for the CLI app)
```

Within my `Cargo.toml`, I've set up a workspace configuration like this:

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["crates/*"]

resolver = "2"
```

For example, consider the `project-foo` crate, which exposes a single subcommand named `FileAction`. This subcommand contains two sub-subcommands.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
pub enum FileAction {
    Copy(CopyCommand),
    Paste(PasteCommand),
}

#[derive(Debug, clap::Args)]
pub struct CopyCommand {
    // Include any relevant options here.
}

impl CopyCommand {
    pub async fn handle(&self) -> Result<()> {
        // handle the code 
    }
}
```

In the `project-core` crate, we manage these sub-subcommands using the `Cli` struct.

```rust
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(subcommand_required = true)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum Commands {
    File {
        #[clap(subcommand)]
        action: FileAction,
    },
}


fn main() {
    let matches = Cli::command().get_matches();
    let cli = Cli::from_arg_matches(&matches).unwrap();

    match cli.command {
        File { action } => match action {
            FileAction::Copy(copy_args) => {
                if let Err(err) = copy_args.handle().await {
                    eprintln!("{}", err);
                }
            },
            FileAction::Paste(paste_args) => {
                if let Err(err) = paste_args.handle().await {
                    eprintln!("{}", err);
                }
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Ideally, my `project-core/Cargo.toml` would look something like this:

```ini
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
project-foo = { path = "../project-foo" }
project-bar = { path = "../project-bar" }
```

This approach doesn't work due to a persistent dependency issue between the crates used in the two subcommands. It doesn't seem likely that this issue will be resolved in the near future.

Note: Cargo features can't be used to solve the problem because of [Feature unification](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification)

My initial idea was to move one crate outside of the `crates` folder so that it isn't automatically compiled when I run `cargo build`. Then, I'd like to find a way to build it from `project-core` and execute it as a subprocess in the CLI defined in `project-core/main.rs`.
Is this approach even feasible, and is it a good solution? Or is there a more straightforward way to resolve this issue

Comment: If creating separate executables and spawning them as subprocesses is feasible only you can tell, you've shared 0 of the code necessary for us to tell. You certainly can make the subcommands executables of their ownes as far as Rust is concerned.

Comment: @cafce25 Editted
Is there a way to make a clap subcommand like this executable?

Comment: I'm not sure but [`cargo`](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/) uses `clap` and has subcommands such as `cargo new`, ... as standalone executables, maybe you can checkout how they do it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why doesn't the straightforward setup work?

Comment: > I don't understand the problem. Why doesn't the straightforward setup work? 

There is a dependency issue between `project-foo` and `project-bar` so they can't compile in the same project

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by patching the crate causing the issue.

In a scenario where two dependencies, such as `project-foo` and `project-bar`, rely on different versions of a third crate, a dependency conflict arises.

Each crate specifies a specific version, leading to this conflict. Fortunately, I found a commit in the third crate that fulfilled both crates' version requirements. I added a patch to my `Cargo.toml` to address this:

```ini
[patch.crates-io.third_crate]
git = "https://github.com/user/third_crate"
rev = "<commit>" # This commit meets both crates' version requirements
```

However, if no suitable commit existed, I would have resorted to forking the crate and making modifications to resolve the issue.